# How do you find the lifecycle status of a tidyverse function or argument?

Tags: r, tidyverse

What's the correct way to work out the [lifecycle stage](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/articles/stages.html) of tidyverse functions? (that is, whether the function/argument is considered `stable`, `experimental`, `deprecated`, or `superseded`)

[image]

#### What I know so far

I *guess* that the documentation will tell us, for example: `library(tidyverse); ?summarise` shows the `.groups` argument as 'experimental'.

Is assuming a function/argument is 'stable' unless it's expressly designated 'experimental', 'deprecated', or 'superseded' correct, or is there a more accurate/easier way to find out whether or not it's 'stable'?

[image]

#### Background

In case it's relevant, the problem I'm trying to solve is that a friend complains of the occasionally deprecated tidyverse function necessitating shiny app maintenance. So I want to suggest they check for 'stable' functions/arguments on their future work to minimise this maintenance. Just after the easiest / most sensible way for them to do that.

Answer (score 9):

A potential solution is to lint your package/script using the [`lint_tidyverse_lifecycle()` function](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/reference/lint_lifecycle.html) from the [lifecycle package](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/index.html) to identify 'unstable' functions, e.g.

(In Rstudio):

```r
library(lifecycle)
lint_tidyverse_lifecycle()
```

Which, in my case, gives me a large number of unstable functions that I need to correct/update/fix:

[image: issues.png]

Most of these are very simple changes (i.e. `dplyr::sample_n()` -> `dplyr::slice_sample()`) and once all of the issues are addressed, all of the tidyverse functions used in the script will be 'stable'.

Answer (score 3):

For debugging code, see `lint_lifecycle`, which searches for matches in files. To find the lifecycle of functions (here specifically for the tidyverse), we can make a custom function. Neither of these approaches identify experimental arguments like `.groups` in `summarise`. It can then lead to frustrating debugging processes later. For those functions, I'd consider finding an alternative that is stable, for example base R `aggregate`.

```
f <- function(type = NULL){
  check_pkgs <- Vectorize(lifecycle:::pkg_lifecycle_statuses, "package")
  pkgs <- tidyverse::tidyverse_packages()
  l <- check_pkgs(pkgs)
  l <- l[lapply(l, length) > 0]
  df <- data.frame(pkg = unlist(l[seq.int(1, length(l), 3)], use.names = F),
                   fun = unlist(l[seq.int(2, length(l), 3)], use.names = F),
                   cycle = unlist(l[seq.int(3, length(l), 3)], use.names = F))
  if(!is.null(type)) subset(df, cycle == type) else df
}

# many functions are "experimental".
f("experimental")
```

For non-tidyverse functions, we can replace `pkgs <- tidyverse_packages()` with

```
att <- .packages()
pkgs <- att[!att %in% rownames(installed.packages(priority="base"))]
```

And if situation requires it, we can do some manual searching by finding

```
needles <- f()$fun
haystack <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()[["contents"]]
```

As an aside, there are a few more stages (no longer recommended by `lifecycle`) that are still used in tidyverse documentation. Choices are *superseded, deprecated, questioning, defunct, experimental, soft-deprecated*. Further caveats are *maturing* and *retired*.